# Get second word from string

Tags: c, memory-management, c-strings, strtok

I'm trying to get the second word from a string in C using `strtok`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char* GetFirstToken(char str[])
{
    const char delim[] = " ";
    char inputCopy [255];
    strcpy(inputCopy, str);
    return strtok(inputCopy, delim);        
}

char* GetSecondToken(char str[])
{
    const char delim[] = " ";
    char inputCopy [255];
    strcpy(inputCopy, str);
    char * ptr = strtok(inputCopy, delim);    
    return strtok(NULL, delim); 
}

int main(void){
    char my_str[100] ="hello world";
    char *first = GetFirstToken(my_str);
    char *second = GetSecondToken(my_str);

    printf("first:%s\n", first);
    printf("second:%s\n", second);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
first: hello

second: wo
```

Why isn't "world" the value of `second`?

Comment: This looks very complex. you would just check the input string character by character, and look for ' ' character to let you know that the first word has ended. Then just take in all the characters until a null character '\0' is found, and you know that the second word has ended. (Because true strings end in a null character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `char inputCopy[255]` inside of each function, and then return a pointer to it. However, the array exists only in the scope of the function, causing **undefined behavior**.

You can avoid this by creating the array in the main, and passing it as an argument to the functions. Also, use `malloc` to dynamically allocate memory for the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char* GetFirstToken(char str[], char inputCopy[], const char delim[])
{
    strcpy(inputCopy, str);
    return strtok(inputCopy, delim);        
}

char* GetSecondToken(char str[], char inputCopy[], const char delim[])
{
    strcpy(inputCopy, str);
    char * ptr = strtok(inputCopy, delim);    
    return strtok(NULL, delim); 
}

int main(void){
    char my_str[100] ="hello world";
    char *inputCopy = malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
    const char delim[] = " ";
    char *first = GetFirstToken(my_str, inputCopy, delim);
    char *second = GetSecondToken(my_str, inputCopy, delim);

    printf("first:%s\n", first);
    printf("second:%s\n", second);

    free(inputCopy);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
first:hello
second:world
```

You can read more about **scopes** in C [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm), and about **malloc** [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm).

Also, notice that `GetFirstToken` and `GetSecondToken` have a similar functionality. Therefore, it is better to have one function that returns the nth words in a given string. Here is the basic idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char my_str[] ="hello world i am a string";
    char* word;

    /* get the first word from the message, seperated by
     * space character */
    word = strtok(my_str, " ");
    printf("1st word: %s\n", word);

    /* the following loop gets the rest of the words until the
     * end of the message */
    int i=2;
    while ((word = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d word: %s\n", i, word);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can read more about such solutions [here](https://gist.github.com/efeciftci/9120921) and also in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904246/c-get-the-nth-word-in-a-string).

Answer (score 3):

The functions return invalid pointers because they point to local arrays that will not be alive after exiting the functions As result using the pointers can invoke undefined behavior.

You could define only one function with one more parameter that specifies which substring you are going to extract.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * GetToken( const char str[], size_t pos )
{
    const char delim[] = " \t";

    char *inputCopy = malloc( ( strlen( str ) + 1 ) );

    char *p = NULL;

    if ( inputCopy != NULL )
    {
        strcpy( inputCopy, str );

        p = strtok( inputCopy, delim );

        while ( p != NULL && pos -- != 0 )
        {
            p = strtok( NULL, delim );
        }

        if ( p != NULL )
        {
            size_t n = strlen( p );
            memmove( inputCopy, p, n + 1 );

            p = realloc( inputCopy, n + 1 );
        }           

        if ( p == NULL )
        {
            free( inputCopy );
        }
    }

    return p;
}


int main(void) 
{
    char my_str[100] ="hello world";
    char *first = GetToken(my_str, 0);
    char *second = GetToken( my_str, 1 );

    if ( first ) printf("first:%s\n", first);
    if ( second ) printf("second:%s\n", second);

    free( first );
    free( second );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And how would I do it to have the correct value stored in my `second` variable?

Comment: @RafaelDuarte, Allocate memory for it inside the function dynamically, using the malloc function.

Comment: Replace `char inputCopy [255];` with `char *inputCopy = malloc(255 * sizeof(char));`